# using force:inputfield in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i am trying to show a object field in edit mode in lightning component.
for that i have  written a lightning component and invoking this from a quick action but i am getting the run time exception as org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: Error Retrieving Field for: v.bam1.name
my code is as below..
Lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" controller="BamEditController">   
    <aura:attribute name="bam1" type="TR_Bank_Account_Master__c" default="{'sObjectType': 'TR_Bank_Account_Master__c'}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInIt}"/>
    <apex:form>
        <force:inputfield value="{!v.bam1.name}"/>
    </apex:form> 
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action =component.get("c.getBanks");

        action.setParams({"bamId": component.get("v.recordId")});

        action.setCallBack(this, function(response){
            var state =  response.getState();
            if(state=== "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.bamId",response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            }
        }
                          );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex controller:

```
public class BamEditController {
@auraEnabled
    public static TR_Bank_Account_Master__c getBanks( ID bamId){
        system.debug('prasad id:'+bamId);
        TR_Bank_Account_Master__c bams;
        if(bamId !=null){
       // id bamID= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        bams = [select id, name,A_C_Status__c,A_C_Number__c,Bank_Name_Familly__c,Bank_Name_Local__c from TR_Bank_Account_Master__c where id =: bamId LIMIT 1];      
        }
        return bams;

    }
}
```

Please correct me where i am wrong..., Thanks

Comment: is N in capital for Name? Lightning is case sensitive. 

It wants fields names as it is stored in database.

{!v.bam1.Name}

Comment: yes @PranayJaiswal it is 'N' only, but i tried by updating to capital N, No luck same error popped up again:(

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here, though you'd be forgiven if you don't see it at first:

```
<aura:attribute name="bam1" 
    type="TR_Bank_Account_Master__c" 
    default="{'sObjectType': 'TR_Bank_Account_Master__c'}"/>
```

Lightning is case-sensitive, so you have a case-sensitive problem here; a record's type should be `sobjectType`, not `sObjectType`:

```
<aura:attribute name="bam1" 
    type="TR_Bank_Account_Master__c" 
    default="{'sobjectType': 'TR_Bank_Account_Master__c'}"/>
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments:

```
    <force:inputfield value="{!v.bam1.name}"/>
```

Would also be an error; you need to observe field capitalization:

```
    <force:inputfield value="{!v.bam1.Name}"/>
```